# How can I point an SCNNode at another SCNNode?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a series of (flat plane) nodes in my scene that I need to have constantly facing the camera.

How can I adjust the transform/rotation to get this working?

Also, where do I make this calculation?

Currently I am trying to make it happen on user interaction in the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` `renderer:updateAtTime:` delegate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an `SCNBillboardConstraint`? That restricts you to iOS 9/El Capitan/tvOS. Add the constraint to each of your flat plane (billboard) nodes.

From the SceneKit Framework Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNBillboardConstraint_Class/index.html

> An SCNBillboardConstraint object automatically adjusts a node’s orientation so that it always points toward the pointOfView node currently being used to render the scene.

In the more general case, `SCNLookAtConstraint` will keep any node's minus-Z axis pointed toward any other node.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much! I was researching Euler formulas to hand-code in the updateAt: delegate method. You saved me from Math, my friend. MATH!